# Angular 9 not producing app.module.ngfactory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am doing an aot compile of angular 9(upgraded from 6) project but I see that no ngFactory files are bein produced. I have a reference of app.module.ngfactory in my main aot file. Something like this:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app/app.module.ngfactory';

enableProdMode();


platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory).catch(err => {
});
```

Any pointers on how to resolve the issue?
TIA

Comment: this issue seams [to be already documented](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14646)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 9 and Ivy, there are no ngfactory files anymore, you should remove the main-aot.ts file

Comment: main-aot.ts file is needed to complie the app in AOT mode

Comment: with ivy you should always use AOT compilation